# Java wrong decimal for extended ascii windows-1252

Tags: java, decimal, ascii, extended-ascii, windows-1252

how can I get the correct decimal for the extended ascii based on windows-1252? Found few symbol will return as unicode instead of ascii number such as below:

```
symbol: ’ expected: 146 return: 8217
symbol: ” expected: 148 return: 8221
```

Comment: Please provide more information on what you are doing, how do you get that character?

Comment: The problem is likely not that you are getting the wrong character value, but that you are analyzing the wrong character.

Comment: this character is from fix which I having issue to generate the correct checksum with counter party

Answer (score 0):

`’` (8217) is a [Unicode Character 'RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK' (U+2019)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm).
`”` (8221) is a [Unicode Character 'RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK' (U+201D)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201d/index.htm).

It seems that your code is expecting:
`’` (146) [Unicode Character 'PRIVATE USE TWO' (U+0092)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/92/index.htm).
`”` (148) [Unicode Character 'CANCEL CHARACTER' (U+0094)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/94/index.htm).

Which are actually from the [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) code page.

So, your code is expecting to read Windows-1252, but is receiving Unicode, and the Windows-1252 to Unicode decoding has already taken place when Java read your original file.

Solution: Since your file is already in Windows-1252, and your code wants that, read the file as bytes, not as text.